# Solve non-linear equation in Python/SageMath

Tags: python, sum, solver, sage

I'm a new user of Python & SageMath.

I have two non-linear equations:

1. `f(x)==h(x)`
2. `g(x)+S_{i,j,k}(x) == 0`

I know I can solve 1. numerically, doing:

```
x = var('x')
find_root(f(x)==h(x), x, x_min, x_max)
```

In 2., `S_{i,j,k}(x)` is a triple sum function of `x` and `i`, `j` and `k` are the indices of the sum. How can I solve it numerically?

Answer (score 1):

Using Python and [sympy](http://www.sympy.org/en/index.html), you can define your `S_{i,j,k}(x)` function using [`sympy.mpmath.nsum()`](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/mpmath/calculus/sums_limits.html#Multidimensional%20sums),
and then use  [`sympy.mpmath.findroot()`](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/mpmath/calculus/optimization.html?highlight=find%20root#mpmath.findroot):

```
import sympy.mpmath

x = sympy.symbols('x')


def S(x_):
    return sympy.mpmath.nsum(lambda i, j: x_*i + j, [0, 2], [3, 4])


print('Function: {}'.format(S(x)))
print('Solution: {}'.format(sympy.mpmath.findroot(S, -1)))
```

prints:

```
Function: 6.0*x + 21.0
Solution: -3.5
```

I chose a linear example but it works with non linear equations too.

Comment: Thanks! When I do            import sympy.mpmath

x = sympy.symbols('x')                A=2                  def S(x): return sympy.mpmath.nsum(lambda i, j,k: (12*A^4*x^6*i^4-30*A^2*x^3*i^2*(j^2+k^2)+3*(j^2+k^2^2)/(2*(A^2*x^3*i^2+j^2+k^2) ^ (7/2)), [1, 500], [1, 500],[1,500])                S(1), the system crush. (^ is the potency **). Is that for the high limits of the summation (500)? In such case, how can I set the tolerance limit?    Best regards!!

Comment: @JosèLuisMietta You are missing a parenthesis. However, even with the correct syntax i get a `MemoryError` simply for trying to call `S(1)` (i guess trying to solve it would be *much* worse). `[1,500]` means _`i` goes from 1 to 500_; using `1-50` i get `S(1)` equal to `9409331700000.48`. I don't know if my answer would work for your problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Using 20 for the limit of the summation (doing that I avoid the crash memory problem), If I try to solve the equation      S(x)=x+2     doing    sympy.mpmath.findroot(S(x) -x -2, 0),    I get the error               "TypeError: unsupported operand parent(s) for '*': 'Symbolic Ring' and '<class 'sympy.mpmath.ctx_mp_python.mpf'>'", What am I doing wrong? Best regards